# Combine two SELECT statements from same table with diff. where condition

Tags: sql

Suppose we have an `Emp` table with `EmpId, Manager, Subb` as three columns.

`Manager` is 1 when `EmpId` is manager, similarly for `subb`.

Require number of manager and subb from table.

Can we combine these two queries into a single `SELECT` query? (want to scan table just once)

```
select count(*) as ManagerNumber from Emp where Manager=1
select count(*) as Subordinate  from Emp where Subb=1.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Manager = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ManagerNumber, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN subb = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Subordinate 
FROM Emp
```

And it is SQL ANSI standard, it will work in all RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks Gamal: your query is quit correct, you just need to replace 0 with null. As count will count all the values whether it is 0 or 1 , but when its null then it will not count.   
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Manager = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS ManagerNumber, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN subb = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Subordinate 
FROM Emp

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
select
    (select count(*) as ManagerNumber from Emp where Manager=1),
    (select count(*) as Subordinate  from Emp where Subb=1)
```

Or each in a row,

```
select count(*) as ManagerNumber from Emp where Manager=1
UNION
    select count(*) as Subordinate  from Emp where Subb=1
```

Comment: Both statements still would scan the table twice which is what Anand does not want

Comment: Want to scan table Emp  just once.